# Issue with Fliter link cliks in adobe DTM?

Tags: javascript, tags, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

when I am clicking first time on filter

s.eVar55 showing value as 'undefined'

however when I am calling my data element which is _satellite.getVar("payal evar55/prop55 test") 
I am getting the correct value
this data element has been mapped to s.eVar55

Please see the attached screenshot [image]

but s.eVar55 is not showing value when first time filter click happened
but from second time onwards it shows the previous value

**"Code which i have written in adobe DTM custom editor"**

```
if(_satellite.getVar("payal evar55/prop55 test") && _satellite.getVar("payal evar55/prop55 test") !== null){
  s.linkTrackVars='eVar55,prop55';
  s.eVar55=_satellite.getVar("payal evar55/prop55 test");
  s.prop55=_satellite.getVar("payal evar55/prop55 test");
}
```

Comment: When does the DE get set? If this happens after the page load (meaning the DE loaded w/o a value) you will not be able to reference the DE directly. I would set your variables (linkTrackVars/linkTrackEvents) and text on the filter click.

Comment: This is not enough information to go on. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't giving enough information to be sure what you're trying to do, but I assume you've set up a data element and you're trying to use it to store the filters that you've clicked. The fact that you're always one step behind is telling me that your load order is what is causing the issue.

The data element is trying to set when the page refreshes but your rule is firing on the click, so its blank the first time and one behind after that.

Personally, I would just set the prop and eVar on the click rule, if you need the data element for some reason, you can set that in the click rule as well:`_satellite.setVar("Element Name",value);`

If you want help setting the values in the click rule, you'll need to give more information and I will update my answer. If the filter value is in an attribute of the target of your click rule, you can use `this.getAttribute('your attr name')`, and if it is simply a text value, you can use `%this.@text%` in the UI to get your desired value.